# Small improved std::list to manage doubloons and pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I am extending `std::list` in order to have access to convenience member functions that simplify my everyday developments (e.g. ways to deal with doubloons, delete all the stored pointers, etc.). I removed some of these member functions, but I kept the essential ones.

```
#ifndef __PJ_LIST_H__
#define __PJ_LIST_H__

#include <list>
#include <iostream>

// This class is a wrapper of std::list to provide some smarter functionalities
template<class T>
class PjList: public std::list<T>
{
    public:

        typedef typename PjList<T>::iterator PjIterator;

        PjList() {};
        virtual ~PjList() {};

        // Helper functions to deal with doubloons
        bool contains(const T& t);
        bool containsDoubloons();
        PjList<T> removeDoubloons();

        // Calls destructor of all list item and empty the list
        void destroyContents();

        // Accessing elements at index
        T& at(int index);

        // Inserting element around "ref"
        bool insertItem(const T& item, const T& ref, bool before = true);

};

template<class T>
bool PjList<T>::contains(const T& t)
{
    PjIterator it;

    for( it = std::list<T>::begin(); it != std::list<T>::end(); it++ )
    {
        if ( *it == t )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<class T>
bool PjList<T>::containsDoubloons()
{
    PjIterator it;
    PjIterator jt;
    int nb_occurence;

    for( it = std::list<T>::begin(); it != std::list<T>::end(); it++ )
    {
        nb_occurence = 0;
        for( jt = std::list<T>::begin(); jt != std::list<T>::end(); jt++ )
        {
            if ( *it == *jt )
                nb_occurence += 1;
        }
        if ( nb_occurence > 1 )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<class T>
PjList<T> PjList<T>::removeDoubloons()
{
    PjList<T> output;

    PjIterator it;
    for( it = std::list<T>::begin(); it != std::list<T>::end(); it++ )
    {
        T& t = *it;
        if ( !output.contains(t) )
            output.push_back(t);
    }

    return output;
}

template<class T>
void PjList<T>::destroyContents()
{
    PjIterator it;

    for( it = std::list<T>::begin(); it != std::list<T>::end(); it++ )
        delete *it;

    std::list<T>::clear();
}

template<class T>
bool PjList<T>::insertItem(const T& t, const T& ref, bool before)
{
    bool ref_found = false;

    PjIterator it;

    for( it = std::list<T>::begin(); it != std::list<T>::end(); it++ )
    {
        if ( *it == ref )
        {
            ref_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( !ref_found )
    {
        std::cerr << "Insertion in list failed since ref item is not found" << std::endl ;
        return false;
    }

    insert(it, t);
    return true;
}

template<class T>
T& PjList<T>::at(int index)
{
    static T dummy;
    int i = 0;
    PjIterator it;

    for( it = std::list<T>::begin(); it != std::list<T>::end(); it++ )
    {
        if ( index == i++ )
            return *it;
    }
    std::cerr << "Bad index " << index << std::endl ;
    return dummy;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Why add destroyContents() when there is clear and erase? Also why doesn't containsDoubloons() use contains()?

Comment: Why doesn't at() check against size() before going into the loop?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: In `containsDoublooons`, instead of iterating from the beginning in the inner loop, you can just iterate from `it` to the end. Earlier elements have already been compared to `*it`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw The `destroyContents` also `delete`s the pointed data.
@kundor I did not think about this, thanks.
@Phrancis Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I see no reason to have this be an entirely new data structure that inherits from `std::list<T>`. All of the new member functions you've defined are really just wrapper functions that could just be delegated to `std::list<T>` functions or functions that could be implemented as regular procedural functions.

For example, the `contains()` and `at()` and `insertItem()` (which should really just be named `insertItemBefore()`) functions could simply be:

```
namespace list_util {

template <class T>
bool contains(const std::list<T>& l, const T& elem)
{
    return std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), elem) != l.end();
}

template <class T>
T& at(const std::list<T>& l, std::size_t index)
{
    assert(index < l.size());
    auto begin = l.begin();
    std::advance(begin, index);
    return *begin;
}

template <class T>
bool insertItemBefore(std::list<T>& l, const T& ref_item, const T& elem)
{
    auto itemItr = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), ref_item);

    // if we found the item, itemItr != l.end()
    if (itemItr != l.end()) {
        l.insert(itemItr, elem);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

You'd have to `#include<algorithm>` and `#include<iterator>` for this to work. Notice that the index parameter is now `std::size_t` to avoid having to check for negative indexes. They could then simply be called as: `list_util::contains(the_list, elem);` and `list_util::at(the_list, the_index);`.

Moreover, `containsDoubloons()` could be implemented using `std::find()` and `destroyContents()` is really just a call to `std::list<T>::clear()`:

```
namespace list_util {

template<class T>
bool containsDoubloons(const std::list<T>& l)
{
    for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) {
        const auto beginItr = std::next(it);
        if (beginItr != l.end() && 
            std::find(beginItr, l.end(), *it) != l.end()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template<class T>
void destroyContents(std::list<T>& l)
{
    l.clear();
}

}
```

Moreover, since the new functions we've written are completely generic and use the STL iterators for all operations, there's no reason to limit them only to `std::list<T>`. We could allow any container of containing `T` to be a parameter. An example is the `contains()` function:

```
template < template <class> class C, class T>
bool contains(const C<T>& cont, const T& elem)
{
    return std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), elem) != cont.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I figure out I need to work on my C++ a little bit...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the idea is sound in the first place.
First, destroyContains is definitely wrong. Use a container ot std::unique_ptr<> if you have reponsibility of the content. If you don't know if you have, solve the issue, that's a really bad code smell.

Then, if you need to have a container of unique elements, why are you using a list? If you need ordering, use a set, if you don't need ordering, use an ordered_set.

What you are trying to do is definitely not what you should be doing. Sorry, you definitely must not do this.

Comment: BTW, the destructor should not be virtual and is useless here as the parent destructor is obviously not virtual.